# How to return node object on programatically node creation

Tags: 8, nodes

I can create  node programmatically  with following snippet

```
 use \Drupal\node\Entity\Node;

// Create node object with attached file.
$node = Node::create([
  'type'        => 'article',
  'title'       => 'Druplicon test',

])->save();
```

but it only returned "1" on successful,I want to return the created node object . how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's [`Entity::save()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21Entity.php/function/Entity%3A%3Asave/8.2.x) that returns the integer, so:

```
$node = Node::create([
  'type'        => 'article',
  'title'       => 'Druplicon test',
]);

$node->save();

return $node;
```

Comment: but there is no nid in $node, I want to get nid of created node.

Comment: `$node->id()` after `$node->save()` will get you that